# T4 method.Attributes empty on Inherited Base Class

Tags: c#, t4

I'm trying to get all of the attributes on a base class. I was able to get the base class (cls.Parent) and get all of the methods on the base class, however when iterating over the methods and getting method.Attributes, it's always empty.

How do I get the attributes on a method in the base class?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's the relevent code:

```
    void LoadAPICalls() {

    IEnumerable<CodeElement> allClasses = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(VisualStudioHelper.CurrentProject.CodeModel.CodeElements, vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass, false);

    foreach(CodeClass item in allClasses) {
        if (!VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllBaseClasses(item).Any(c => c.FullName == "System.Web.Http.ApiController"))
            continue;

        //Write out the class here.
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var className = item.FullName.Substring(item.FullName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1).Replace("Controller", "");
#>export class <#=className#>
{<#+
        var curItem = item;
        while (true) {
            var allMethods = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllMethods(curItem);
            foreach(CodeFunction method in allMethods) {       

                IEnumerable<CodeElement> allAttributes = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetAllCodeElementsOfType(method.Attributes, vsCMElement.vsCMElementAttribute, true);       
                foreach (CodeElement attribute in allAttributes)
                {
                    if (attribute.Kind != vsCMElement.vsCMElementAttribute)
                        continue;

                    switch(attribute.FullName) {
                        case "System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute": 
                            WriteHttpPost(className, method, sb);
                            break;
                        case "System.Web.Http.HttpGetAttribute": 
                            WriteHttpGet(className, method, sb);
                            break;
                        case "System.Web.Http.HttpPutAttribute": 
                            WriteHttpPut(className, method, sb);
                            break;
                        case "System.Web.Http.HttpDeleteAttribute":
                            WriteHttpDelete(className, method, sb);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            } 
            curItem = VisualStudioHelper.CodeModel.GetBaseClass(curItem);
            if (curItem == null)
                break;
        }

        #>    
}
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Updated the original content. Note that I'm using the helper functions from Tangible, however it does it with the direct functions as well.